# iOS Drag-and-Drop Alignment Guides

Tags: ios, alignment

I'm looking to develop an iOS app that includes drag and droppable interface elements, but with alignment guides like those in Keynote or OmniGraffle or Interface Builder (the [yellow lines](http://stoneship.org/pub/keynote-guides.png) in Keynote) such that when you drag something near enough to vertical or horizontal alignment with another object in the canvas, it displays a guide line and automatically snaps into to alignment.

So far, I haven't been able to find any published API to implement this. Does such a thing exist anywhere? It's a little bit difficult of a concept to Google successfully. If not, any pointers on rolling my own with a minimum of pain?

Comment: Hey any luck with this ? Can you point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 5):

There is no standard API provided by iOS. You have to implement it yourself.

This isn't exactly what you want, but I threw together a little sample app that lets you drag icons around the screen that snap into place like on the iPhone home screen: [Tiles](http://undefinedvalue.com/2010/02/05/iphone-sample-code-tiles).  It doesn't draw any guide lines, so you'll have to figure that out yourself.